# com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.JavascriptLibrary is not working in selenium 3

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am using JavaScriptLibrary in my automation framework with selenium 3.

JavascriptLibrary is not working.

```
JavascriptLibrary javascript = new JavascriptLibrary();
javascript.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver, "triggerEvent", ele, "change");
```

What is the alternative way to perform above action?

Comment: not working is very broad, try explaining the error, giving the error message and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

The library `JavascriptLibrary` has been removed from Selenium 3. You can however inject customized events with `executeScript`:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));", ele);
```